# Format a string to a date in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as shown below, the date column is a string(MMMM-yyyy).

I want to select the latest row for an ID. For ID # 2, the latest date would be August-2020 with the price of 45.40

```
ID   Date         Price
2    August-2020  45.40    
2    July-2020    42.30
```

I've tried the `format(date, 'MMMM-yyyy) as formatted date`  and `STR_TO_DATE(date, '%MMMM-%yyyy')` but I can't get it to convert to a date so I can order the column. I want to keep the date in this format, I just need to order it for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_to_date()` to convert the string to a date; a little trick is needed to make the original value a complete date string before conversion, so:

```
str_to_date(concat(date, '-01'), '%M-%Y-%d')
```

To filter the table on the latest date per id, you would do:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where date = (
    select date
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id
    order by str_to_date(concat(date, '-01'), '%M-%Y-%d') desc
    limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to proper format specifiers for MySQL.  I would expect this to work:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('August-2020', '%M-%Y')
```

However, it appears that you need:

```
select str_to_date(concat('01-', 'August-2020'), '%d-%M-%Y')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5841e1c2688559d22d06dc42028d140e) is a db<>fiddle.